# Equivalent of _byteswap_ulong in JavaScript/Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

What is the equivalent of _byteswap_ulong in JavaScript?

I'm currently using the following C++ code:

```
int tag = 2832779;
tag = _byteswap_ulong(tag) >> 8;
```

The result of tag is `9124193`.

I tried doing the same in JavaScript:

```
var tag = 2832779;
tag = (((tag >> 24) & 0x000000FF) | ((tag >> 8) & 0x0000FF00) | ((tag << 8) & 0x00FF0000) | ((tag << 24) & 0xFF000000)) >> 8;
```

However, the result of tag (in JS) is `-7653077`.

Is it possible to swap bytes in JavaScript the same way it's possible in C++?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: There is no equivalent that's part of the standard runtime. You'd probably have to do this with typed arrays.

Comment: To elaborate, typed arrays are necessary because bit operations (such as `|`, `&`, shifts) implicitly convert numbers to signed 32-bit integers.  There is no support for unsigned integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you meant 91241**39**, here is a simple function that should work:

```
function byteSwap(n) {
  n = n.toString(16);
  if ((n.length % 2) !== 0)
    n = '0' + n;
  return parseInt(n.match(/([a-z0-9]{2})/g).reverse().join(''), 16);
}

console.log(byteSwap(2832779));
// outputs: 9124139
```